# How to properly set up an X11 startup script

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to get my desktop to startup with the background and resolution that I have preset, however I can't seem to figure out how to do this. So far I've tried making a ~./.xprofile with xrandr and feh commands in it, but I think my window manager doesn't read the xprofile, I then tried to use xorg.conf and put it in /etc/X11 with settings I found online, the xserver says it's using it but my resolution stays the same. Right now what I have is just a sessionInit script that I call when I log into the window manager that sets resolution and background, however I'd like to get rid of it and do it the right way.

This is my system info: Running in VMWare on Windows 10, installed Ubuntu minimal, using Awesome window manager. I start my x session with startx manually. Thanks.

Edit: Also right now I have a problem with any executable that starts, they all use what seems to me the default resolution, because all the menus are huge, I fixed it on the browser by giving it --force-device-scale-factor flag however my compiler won't take none of it. Can anyone tell me what file all these execs are reading to get their resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the feh package? `sudo apt-get install feh`

run`feh --bg-scale /path/to/image.file`

add `sh ~/.fehbg &` to the bottom of xinitrc (`/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`).

When you next run startx it will load `~/.fehbg` and set the background that you specified with `feh --bg-scale /path/to/image.file`

There are other options instead of feh. Awesome has its own built in way to set the background but it seems to be hit or miss if it works. You might have to comment out the `wallpaper_cmd` line located in `/usr/share/awesome/themes/default/theme` (what ever your theme is). Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I mentioned in my OP that I'm using feh already, right now I have it in a separate script along with xrandr command. I'll see if putting it in xinitrc works.

Comment: Ok so I tried putting the feh command along with xrandr into xinitrc, but the server wouldn't even start, and yes I made sure the syntax was correct. But now the weird thing is that I can't get the server to start even after I deleted those lines! That was the only thing I changed was the two lines in xinit rc. I've rebooted a dozen times, the server logs don't have any errors either. Not sure what to do now. Thanks a lot Mostafa, great advice to mess with global xinitrc script.